# Dotenv doesn't work in production (Create-React-App, AWS)

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, dotenv

I'm using 'dotenv' in my Create-React-App to hide Google api key.

```html
// .env
REACT_APP_API_KEY=*********
```

```html
// index.html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=%REACT_APP_API_KEY%&libraries=places"></script>
```

On localhost it works perfectly, but in production it can't access environment variables:

[image]

Am I missing something? I'm new to this and I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: `create-react-app` guide to [using environment variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/). Do note that these cannot be used for *hiding* the keys on the frontend